# How to register an implicit system broadcast like "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" which is not supported in the Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-8.0-oreo

How to register an implicit system broadcast like `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`  which is not supported in the Android `Oreo`

Answer (score 0):

You register it the same way as you always have, as it [is documented as being on the implicit `Intent` broadcast whitelist](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

Comment: I am using this   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);   but it is not working in oreo . it is working fine in other android version except oreo

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem, showing your code and how you are testing it.